# SQL Server Returns Incomplete Data From Completed Transaction

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, isolation-level

I have two C# applications (call them Writer and Reader) using a SQL Server database.

Writer starts a Repeatable Read transaction, calls a stored procedure to insert a record into a table (call it Parent), and then zero or more times it calls another stored procedure to insert related records into another table (call it Child), and then commits the transaction.

Reader calls a stored procedure which selects new records from Parent with a left outer join on Child (using WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) on Parent), for which columns coming from Child are null only when zero Child records were inserted.

I am baffled and horrified by the following reproducible sequence of events:

1. Writer starts a transaction.
2. Writer inserts into Parent.
3. Reader calls its stored procedure, which blocks because of the pending transaction.
4. Writer inserts into Child.
5. Writer commits the transaction.
6. Reader returns a row in which the columns from the Child table are NULL; **the successfully-written data in the Child table is effectively LOST**, even though subsequent queries show it was successfully written.

How is it possible for the Reader to get data from Parent but not from Child, if both the Parent and Child writes are in the same transaction?!

(I tried eliminating the HOLDLOCK hint on Parent in the Reader stored procedure, and adding SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE, but all that did was start generating deadlocks.)

*Additional Finding Jan 28 2019:* The problem appears only to occur in my load test simulator when a connection to the database is initially made; when the connection is retrieved from the .NET connection pool, data is retrieved as expected.  Disabling pooling with SqlConnection.ClearPool(con); causes the problem to occur even after the first connection.

Comment: When you say it's lost, do you mean it truly isn't ever written, or just wasn't returned in the reader transaction? Like... what if you queried it *after* the insert transaction was finished... is the record there? HOLDLOCK is equivalent to SERIALIZABLE. Why the UPDLOCK on a SELECT?

Comment: @scsimon Good questions; sorry for the confusion.  It's lost in the sense that Reader never sees the data.  When Reader calls its stored procedure after the Writer transaction is committed, data is returned as expected.  The WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) hint was added many years ago to eliminate rare deadlock errors that were occurring.

Comment: Removing the hints from the SELECT and NOT adding the serialized isolation would resolve this I suspect and not cause deadlocks. The serialized would introduce deadlocks. Have you tried that?

Comment: @scsimon I'm afraid removing the hints and not adding SERIALIZED returned us to the state we had many years ago, in which eventually we end up encountering a deadlock.

Comment: So eventually once in a while? Did you troubleshoot the deadlock instead of tossing hints? Do you have a graph?

Comment: @scsimon Yes, the deadlocks occur on a smallish percentage of Reader calls.  It's my recollection that when we analyzed the deadlocks when they first started occurring, our conclusion was that adding the hints was the resolution.  I don't have the graph we used back then.

Comment: I understand and that makes this hard. So, many things can affect this. First, any cumulative updates or upgrades of the SQL version could change it. Other DB and application code changes could affect it among others. I’d remove the hints and wait for the deadlocks and capture those for analysis so you aren’t operating blind.